# NLP Text Pre Processing

Tags: python, nlp

I'm trying to pre-process some case judgement files available on the internet. These files are in JSON format but some of the files have strange text in them. I initially thought this could be utf-8 encoding issue but it doesn't solve the problem.

Below is a sample json text:
I would like to clean the text and perform text analytics to identify Named Entities.

```
Karnataka High Court
Shinde, on 4 January, 2010
Author: Mohan Shantanagoudar
EN 'THE 1-ma COURT OF KARNATAKA CIRCUIT Bmca
AT GUI.-BARGA T '

DA'1'ED THIS THE ow: DAY OF' JANUAR§f"'2C}.'1~{3._j:    

BEFORE

HONBLE MRJUSTICE MOHAN SE3-®;si*;';axt$:;é; GOU:>%a$gi=:;;vT 3
\,v.P_Ng.40334;2QQ8 (éMl<:pcT;« ""  
Bmmfaam:     

SURESE-I CHANDRA ,   - 
S/O LATE,' SHANKECRRAO .SHI'E$II);E§ "
AGE ABOUT 52 YEARS, ' L 9'   
occ:AGR1CUL*mR1=:. &A9voc';acY ' 
R:E:s1DENT Oms'-Q'NME§,KuN_19A..4  _ .«
TALUK: B}iALKI, §*éOW_R.E.S;IDING M' " 
H.No.19--1C'--,-'4, NfEW*"A'DARf3}i"*~COLCNY_ '
BIDAR. D1533: BEAR.   

 1111    ._ ..PETITEONERS
{SR1 K;..M.<j;HAi:r;..;x);3voa::é:1?:x;3-- I

SU'N'I'i'A xa§;"0% SU3§iE_§SA1~~§ bciégxmorarx SE-{KNEE
AG  93395'? 4-:2. YE2}\RSs
ace: 1~§Q"TU_SI*3WII'%"i9:., ..... .4 «

 " R.E;s:E>::é§'r%'a3:§«f H.N9.§9/'Q 1, I\z'IUKEEI\EiE) NAGAR,

 ' Eﬁ}£;'§E{Ekf§iE'E3E§TEEi§._S0L§s.£3"ﬁE?;{

., REZSELQNDE,-'1'éf"§'



'EE'1§¢:~:.i£'€;:"§i. ?€'€.§%i<3:;. 32$ féieé :m.{§%3:' :%r%':££:E€$ 226 5: 22?

 :3? %;E:{7:-§:{m::s€é:§':,z':'E.i:';:: Q? §E.1€:§§.f&-'£1; grag,-iiiggg if: q':,:.::2;-33%: {her {ﬁfﬁﬁf
```

Can anyone help me with some direction to solve this problem? Are these files corrupted?

Comment: Looks like bad OCR to me?

Comment: This has nothing to do with code itself, so I suggest asking this on a site from [this list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254090/858527).